# In a Max Flow problem, how to find all possible sets of paths that give max flow?

Tags: algorithm, graph, network-flow

I understand that [Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ford-fulkerson-algorithm-for-maximum-flow-problem/) can find the maximum flow that can flow from source (`s`) to sink (`t`) in a flow network.
But is there an algorithm that finds all possible sets of paths that give the max flow?

An example:
In this network below, all edges have a capacity of 1. It's not hard to see that the max flow from `s` to `t` is 3. But how to find the combinations of paths that carry that flow?

Expected outputs:
Path set 1: `s-0-1-t, s-2-3-t, s-5-6-t`
Path set 2: `s-0-1-t, s-2-4-t, s-5-6-t`
Path set 3: `s-0-3-t, s-2-4-t, s-5-6-t`
Path set 4: `s-0-4-t, s-2-3-t, s-5-6-t`

[image]

A similar question was asked [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13403/finding-paths-from-the-result-of-max-flow) but didn't seem to get a clear answer.

Comment: Can we assume that all of the arcs are cap 1? That makes the problem a lot easier.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, all arcs are cap 1.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, I'm assuming that all arcs are directed and capacity 1.

The high-level pseudocode is

```
define EnumerateFlows(G, s, t):
    if G has no s-t path:
        yield []  # solution with no paths
    else:
        for P in EnumeratePaths(G, s, t):
            derive G' = G - P
            let s-u be the first arc in P
            derive G'' = G' - {arcs s-v such that v < u}  # ensure canonically ordered solutions only
            for F in EnumerateFlows(G'', s, t):
                yield [P, F...]  # solution with P followed by the elements of F
```

where the return value of the function is a list of all of the `yield`s made in its body. The output needs postprocessing to remove the non-maximum flows.

`EnumeratePaths` undoubtedly has a solution on Stack Overflow, but for completeness,

```
define EnumeratePaths(G, s, t):
    if s = t:
        yield [s]
    else:
        for u in {successors of s in t}:
            for P in EnumeratePaths(G - {s-u}, u, t):
                yield [s, P...]
```

To improve `EnumerateFlows`, it's worth adding a check to make sure that there still exists a max flow in the residual graph.

As for low-level implementation advice, my suggestion would be to use an adjacency list representation for `G` and splice arcs in and out of the lists. On the other hand, maybe your graphs are small enough that it doesn't matter.